# Information in Community Promotion Ads statistics

Tags: support, advertising

[This page](https://meta.superuser.com/ads/display/3957) contains statistics for the current community promotion ads. Unfortunately, it does not contain enough data for users to judge the numbers that are shown.

Are all ads shown equally often? Relative to the number of votes received? Randomly? *How often* is each ad shown?

Without this information, the number of clicks is telling us nothing about the success of the ad (Clickthrough Rate). Do users just not care about Greenshot and Twitter, or is something else going on here?

---

So, how often are the individual ads shown relative to each other? Is it roughly equal for each ad, or is it a more advanced formula?

Comment: I might rewrite this topic to a `feature-request` to add the missing data once this question is answered.

Comment: @kinokijuf Daniel said he wanted to *rewrite it*, and only *once* it was sufficiently answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The community promotion ad that gets shown is (equally) randomly chosen.