# Rollbacks are not shown as revisions in a user profile's responses view

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-profiles, revisions

[This post](https://meta.superuser.com/q/4178/22317) has been edited, and afterwards was rolled back:

[image]

---

Revision 3, the rollback of the previous edit, does not show up in my user profile's *responses » revisions* list:

[image]

Comment: When do you earn your 'bug hunter' badge? :P

Answer (score 3):

I've pushed a fix for this.  Rollbacks will now be included as a revision as part of a user's responses starting with our next build.

(rev > 2012.6.12.2915)